# Converting Individual Excel Sheets as Individual PDF Files

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am just trying to use VBA to create create/save individual excel sheets as individual PDF files.

I came across this online:

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsPDFs()
Dim sFile       As String
Dim sPath       As String
Dim wks         As Worksheet

With ActiveWorkbook
    sPath = .Path & "\"
    For Each wks In .Worksheets
            sFile = wks.Name & ".pdf"
            wks.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                    Filename:=sPath & sFile, _
                                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
                                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                    OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next wks
End With
End Sub
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Run-time error '5': 
>   Invalid procedure call or argument

For someone not 100% familiar with VBA, what's invalid?

Thanks

Comment: `ExportAsFixedFormat` is method of `Workbook` not `Worksheet`

Comment: Right, I have a Workbook with individual Worksheets, which I'd like to Save as Individual PDFs.

Comment: Your code ran fine on my machine - Win10 Excel-365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, your code runs fine *(Win-10, Excel-365)*.  I first:

Saved the *.xlsm* file to insure `Spath` exists
`Selected` an area on each worksheet to insure it will be PDF'ed correctly

Comment: Oh, snap. I'm on Windows 7 with Office 2010.  Any alternations I can do for that?

Comment: @kazzi  That is **not** the issue.  Your code also ran fine on my old Dell (*Win-7 Excel-2007*)

Comment: Then I'm not sure why I'm getting the issue.
I went to VBA (ALT + F11), Insert > Module > Pasted the code > Ran it, and got the above error

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I saved the file as a xlsm, then ran it

Comment: I just added it to a different test document and it worked. I guess it has something to do with my current document, probably because it's linked out to other sources. Thanks for your help!